# "No connected camera" on MacBook Pro High Sierra

Tags: macbook-pro, high-sierra, camera

MacBook Pro Retina mid 2012. The error "No connected camera" could be "solved" by "sudo killall VDCAssistant" years ago.

Today the error comes again but VDCAssistant cannot be killed. I have restarted the MBP several times but no luck.

The camera works if I login High Sierra with another (admin) account.

Question: how to make it work for my daily account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a conflict with something that is running in your personal account.

Try logging into your account holding down the shift key. Hold it until everything has settled, it can take a minute or two. This will prevent login apps from running.

See if the problem remains.

Comment: By pressing Shift on start up, OS X entered safe mode and the camera works. Then I started it in normal mode, the camera still works! Although I don't know why.

Comment: Facetime works after every update and then stops working after the first sleep/sign out. Zoom and other video apps can use the camera. The safe mode trick worked, but I wonder why too. I'm on Catalina

Answer (score 0):

If it works in other user spaces, just not in yours, it may be tied to the parental controls which includes a camera exclusion.  I would check the System Preferences / Parental Controls and see if there is an anomalous toggle on "Allow use of camera".